# what's the behavior of tf.trian.optimizer when loss is a vector

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

Suppose log_prob is a vector rather than a scalar. What will the following code do?
Thank you!

```

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)
minimize = optimizer.minimize(log_prob)
session.run(minimize, feed_dict={action : act, feat : s_batch})
```

```

Comment: It's just going to sum log_prob to get a scalar rather than computing the Jacobian. See discussion here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675

Comment: @AllenLavoie - could you turn your comment into an answer, since you nailed it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[tf.gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients), and therefore `Optimizer` `minimize` calls, sum loss Tensors to get a scalar rather than computing the Jacobian. See this discussion of Jacobians in TensorFlow for background: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675